# Objects comparison with recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

Consider the following function's blueprint which tries to compare two objects:

```
function objectCompare(a,b,path){ 
    for (var prop in a) {
      path=prop;
      if (a.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !(b.hasOwnProperty(prop))) {
                ...
          return false;
      }
      ...
      if (detectType(a[prop])==='Object'){
          if (!objectCompare(a[prop],b[prop],path)) 
               return false;
      }
      ...
    }
      return true;
}
```

`detectType` is my own function which checks the type of a variable. My problem is that I want to enrich variable `path` every time we have a recursive call. However, at the same time when recursive calls finish, `path` has to traverse the remaining property names of the initial object without being enriched...
Imagine the following objects:

```
var Obj1 = {
        p1: 's',
        p2: {
          p1: {a: { propA: 'a', propB: 'b' }},
          p2: 'g',
        }
      };

var Obj2 = {
        p1: 's',
        p2: {
          p1: {a: { propA: 'a', propB: 'c' }},
          p2: 'g',
        }
      };
```

I want `path` when function `objectCompare`returns to have the following value: `p2.p1.a.propB`  Namely, the point which makes the two objects different. How may I achieve that?

Comment: There are already lots of questions and answers about comparing objects in Javascript.

Comment: @ILIAS, if all the objects have a strict order of properties, the comparison can be done in a much-much simpler way

Comment: Could you give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the current key to the path and pass the new path to the recursive call. Consider:

```js
console.info=function(x){document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(x,0,3)+'</pre>')}
//--

// compare: return path if a,b are different, null otherwise

function compare(a, b, path) {

    var ta = typeof a,
        tb = typeof b;

    // different types - fail
    
    if (ta !== tb) {
        return path;
    }
    
    // scalars - null if equal, path if not

    if (ta !== 'object') {
        return a === b ? null : path;
    }
    
    // make a set of keys from both objects

    var keys = Object.keys(a).concat(Object.keys(b)).filter(function(x, i, self) {
        return self.indexOf(x) === i;
    });

    // for each key in set, compare values
    
    var res = null;

    keys.some(function(k) {
        return res = compare(a[k], b[k], path.concat(k));
    });

    // return null or the first failed path
    
    return res;
}

//

var Obj1 = {
        p1: 's',
        p2: {
          p1: {a: { propA: 'a', propB: 'b' }},
          p2: 'g',
        }
      };

var Obj2 = {
        p1: 's',
        p2: {
          p1: {a: { propA: 'a', propB: 'c' }},
          p2: 'g',
        }
      };



var res = compare(Obj1, Obj2, [])
console.info(res);
```

Comment: Terrific solution!! Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks! It requires some more work to handle `null` values correctly though (as in `compare({a:null},{b:null})`).

Comment: May I ask you a big favor? Is it possible to have access to some of your Javascript  projects? Your code styling is just magnificent. I 'd like to study and learn from them since I want to find a job in UK and I have to ameliorate my code styling. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The library [`deep-diff`](https://github.com/flitbit/diff) does what you need.

The above reference presents this example code:

```
var diff = require('deep-diff').diff;

var lhs = {
    name: 'my object',
    description: 'it\'s an object!',
    details: {
        it: 'has',
        an: 'array',
        with: ['a', 'few', 'elements']
    }
};

var rhs = {
    name: 'updated object',
    description: 'it\'s an object!',
    details: {
        it: 'has',
        an: 'array',
        with: ['a', 'few', 'more', 'elements', { than: 'before' }]
    }
};

var differences = diff(lhs, rhs);
```

The code snippet above would result in the following structure describing the differences:

```
[ { kind: 'E',
    path: [ 'name' ],
    lhs: 'my object',
    rhs: 'updated object' },
  { kind: 'E',
    path: [ 'details', 'with', 2 ],
        lhs: 'elements',
        rhs: 'more' },
  { kind: 'A',
    path: [ 'details', 'with' ],
    index: 3,
    item: { kind: 'N', rhs: 'elements' } },
  { kind: 'A',
    path: [ 'details', 'with' ],
    index: 4,
    item: { kind: 'N', rhs: { than: 'before' } } } ]
```

Notably the `path` property is much like your desired output.

Comment: I want to construct my own function, not using a library and I have this specific problem with `path`